# How to get rid of the "You are pasting text into a string..." dialog or skip it?

Tags: front-end, dialog-window

Consider the following example:

```
CopyToClipboard["1\t2"];
Button["Paste", FrontEndTokenExecute["Paste"]]
CellPrint @ Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes[""], "Input"]
```

Now move your cursor between the quote characters in the newly printed cell and press the button. You'll get this choice dialog asking you how to paste the characters:

[image]

Is there a way to programmatically disable this dialog and just pick a default paste? It doesn't even really matter to me which type of paste it uses; I just don't want the message to show up and hold up evaluation.

## Edit

To clarify: the string on the clipboard could be anything; I just picked this one as an easy example to illustrate the problem. Assume you have no control over what's on the clipboard.

Comment: Does using `CopyToClipboard["\"" <> "1\t2" <> "\""];
Button["Paste", FrontEndTokenExecute["Paste"]]` instead solve your problem? I mean copy to clipboard with `\"` on both ends of the string and then pasting on a plain cell instead in between `""`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan The string copied to the clipboard is there to illustrate the problem; you should assume that this string can come from anywhere and you don't have control over it.

Comment: You might have no control over what is on the clipboard but if you have control over pasting then you can always prepend and append `"\""` to the string from the clipboard and only then pasting.

Comment: This prompt cannot be suppressed by the user.

Comment: If "Raw InputForm" works for you, something like `CellPrint@Cell["","Input"]` could be used so it completely avoids dealing with boxes (at this stage).

Comment: @Silvia Actually, that might work for me. If you post that as an answer, I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the popup can not be suppressed by users ([according to ihojnicki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275860#comment688866_275860)), the situation could be completely avoided by using `CellPrint @ Cell["", "Input"]` instead as a workaround, so the generated cell is in "Raw InputForm" mode, skipping anything about parsing and boxes.